# Taxonomy ID by Post ID in custom endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

I making custom endpoint for my custom post type. The one thing is the taxonomy ID. I need to get taxonomy ID by post ID. `get_terms( 'gallery_tax', $post->ID )` gives me array with all taxonomy object

```
function wl_posts() {
    $args = [
    'numberposts' => 9999,
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
  ];

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  $data = [];
  $i = 0;

  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
    $data[$i]['fimg_url'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'large');
    $data[$i]['proizvoditel'] = get_field('proizvoditel', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['tip'] = get_field('tip', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['razmer'] = get_field('razmer', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['forma'] = get_field('forma', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['rost'] = get_field('rost', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['ves'] = get_field('ves', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['ohvat'] = get_field('ohvat', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['vozrast'] = get_field('vozrast', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['galereya'] = get_field('galereya', $post->ID);
    $data[$i]['taxonomy'] = get_terms( 'gallery_tax', $post->ID );
    $i++;
  }

  return $data;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'gallery', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wl_posts',
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get_terms('gallery_tax')` will give you all the terms in a taxonomy.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms

You get all the existing terms in your taxonomy. So this is why you get the result.

---

Using `get_the_terms($post->ID, 'gallery_tax')` will give you **all taxonomy terms attached to the post**.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

You get all the terms that have been assigned to your post.

---

If you want to display the **name of the taxonomy itself** and not display the terms associated with the post, you can first get all the names of the taxonomies outside of your post loop and then get the taxonomy name inside of your foreach:

```
...
$data = [];
$i = 0;
$taxnames = get_taxonomies('','names');

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    ...
    $data[$i]['taxonomy'] = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxnames, array("fields" => "names"));
    $i++;
}

...
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomies/

Comment: Thank's. It works. Can you also give comments about how to make filters by that fields and by per_page? In this case they doesn't work.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer as it solved your issue. You can create a new question and post the link here in the comments so I get notfified. I think i can also help you with this new question.